# Can a star be massive enough to go 'supernova' yet not be massive enough to leave behind a neutron star? Or, perhaps vice versa?

Tags: observational-astronomy, supernova, neutron-star, main-sequence, theories

From what I understand, stars that explode as a supernova at the end of their lives become either a black hole or a neutron star, and less massive stars that do not explode become white dwarves, but...

Do those two mass limits overlap exactly?

Answer (score 2):

This diagram from the Wikipedia article on supernovas mostly answers your question I think.
[image: supernova diagram]
There is in fact an interval that is expected to not produce a remnant, but it is not at the lower end of the mass range, interestingly. Instead it's a result of the particular mechanism that triggers the supernova for these heavy stars, which blows the core apart entirely.